# Как посчитать количество повторений каждого значения в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив: `[1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5]`.

Числа могут быть различные. Мне нужно посчитать количество повторений каждого числа. То есть, например, для вышеуказанного массива:

```
число 1 == 3 раза
число 3 == 2 раза
число 4 == 2 раза
число 5 == 1 раз
```

Comment: на собеседованиях частенько такое спрашивают :)

Comment: мне для расчета итогов пройденного на сайте теста . Вывожу результат в зависимости от макс. кол-ва повторений того или иного числа.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [методом reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
document.write('<pre>', JSON.stringify(
  [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5].reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {}), null, 2), '</pre>');
```

Вариант без стрелочных функций

```js
var result = [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(acc, el) {
  acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>', JSON.stringify(
  result, null, 2), '</pre>');
```

Comment: круто, но я не понимаю  этот код :( Копирую себе - получаю синтакс. ошибки :( А хотелось бы получить объект в переменной :)

Comment: @amijin, ошибки могут быть из-за `=>` не во всех браузерах еще имплементированы стрелочные функции. Добавил вариант без них

Answer (score 10):

Самое простое решение:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5];
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
    var a = arr[i];
    if (result[a] != undefined)
        ++result[a];
    else
        result[a] = 1;
}
for (var key in result)
    document.write('число ' + key + ' == ' + result[key] + ' раз(а) <br>');
```

Можно использовать метод `forEach` для массивов:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5];
var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(a){
    if (result[a] != undefined)
        ++result[a];
    else
        result[a] = 1;
});
for (var key in result)
    document.write('число ' + key + ' == ' + result[key] + ' раз(а) <br>');
```

Применив небольшую хитрость, можно записать ещё короче:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5];
var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(a){
    result[a] = result[a] + 1 || 1;
});
for (var key in result)
    document.write('число ' + key + ' == ' + result[key] + ' раз(а) <br>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Эффективный алгоритм: сортируем числа, проходим по массиву, считаем повторения. В отличии от тупого перебора(прошлись по каждому числу и посчитали его количество) который работает за O(N^2) такой алгоритм работает за O(N log N). Хотя автору темы вряд-ли нужен эффективный алгоритм, но кому-то может пригодиться.

Answer (score 1):

```
const result = arr.reduce((acc, rec, index) => {
    return (typeof acc[rec] !== 'undefined') 
      ? { ...acc, [rec]: acc[rec] + 1 } 
      : { ...acc, [rec]: 1 }
}, {})
```

Comment: данный ответ чем-то отличается от уже присутствовавших?

Comment: Можно удалить `return` и `{}` вокруг него.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и верный вариант использовать метод `.filter`

```
[1,2,3,4,4,4,5,4,1,5,4].filter(item => item === 4).length // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

код по "эффективному алгоритму", который описан выше:

```
   function duplicateCount(text){

let str = text.toLowerCase().split("").sort();
let resultArr = []; 
let k = 1;

for (let i of str){


if (i == str[k]){
if (!resultArr.includes(i)){
   resultArr.push(i);
    }
  }
  k++;
}

return resultArr.length
};
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, проще всех перечисленных выше:

```
let arr = [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5];
let count = {};

for (let elem of arr) {
    if (count[elem] === undefined) {
    count[elem] = 1;
    } else {
    count[elem]++;
    }
}
console.log(count); // выведет {1: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var currectObj = {};
var currectArr = [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5];

var setNewValueInObj = (arrValue, arrInput, objOutput) => {
    var buffs = [];

    arrInput.forEach((e) => {
        if (e === arrValue) {
            buffs.push(e);
        }
    });

    objOutput[arrValue] = buffs.length;
}

[...currectArr].forEach((e) => {
    setNewValueInObj(e, currectArr, currectObj);
});

console.log(currectObj);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]